# Note taking app (saves notes to an array)

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-oriented

I created the following app (only saves the notes in an array so no a proper note taking app). I would like to know how I would make this code more object orientated.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ektyL5hg/)

**script.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var notesArray = [],
        count = 0;

    function listRefresh() {
        $('#list').empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < notesArray.length; i++) {
            var name = notesArray[i].name,
                date = notesArray[i].date,
                dateString,
                month,
                element;

            month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            dateString = date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();

            element = $('<li data-id="' + notesArray[i].id + '" data-name="' + notesArray[i].name + '">');

            element.append($('<div class="div-name">').text(name));
            element.append($('<div class="div-date">').text(dateString));

            $('#list').append(element);
        }
    }

    $('#list').on('click', 'li', function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id'),
            content = '',
            name = $(this).data('name');


        console.log("name: ", name)
        $('#list li.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        for (var i = 0; i < notesArray.length; i++) {
            if (notesArray[i].id === id) {
                content = notesArray[i].content;
            }
        }

        $('#edit-name').val(name);
        $('#edit-content').val(content);

        //$('#div-edit').css('display', 'inline-block');
        $('#div-edit').removeClass('hide');
    })

    $('#add').on('click', function() {
        var name = $('#name').val(),
            content = $('#content').val(),
            date = new Date();

        if (name === "") {
            alert("Please enter a name for the note");
        } else {
            notesArray.push({
                id: count,
                name: name,
                content: content,
                date: date
            })
        }

        count++;

        $('#content').val('');
        $('#name').val('');

        listRefresh();
    })

    $('#save').on('click', function() {
        var id = $('#list li.selected').data('id'),
            name = $('#edit-name').val(),
            content = $('#edit-content').val();

        for (var i = 0; i < notesArray.length; i++) {
            if (notesArray[i].id === id) {
                notesArray[i].name = name;
                notesArray[i].content = content;
                break;
            }
        }

        listRefresh();

        $('#list li[data-id="' + id + '"]').addClass('selected');

    })

    $('#cancel').on('click', function() {
        //$('#div-edit').css('display', 'none');
        $('#div-edit').addClass('hide');
        $('#list li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    })

    $('#remove').on('click', function() {
        var id = $('#list li.selected').data('id');

        var r = confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this note?');
        if (r) {
            for (var i = 0; i < notesArray.length; i++) {
                if (notesArray[i].id === id) {
                    notesArray.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }

            listRefresh();

            //$('#div-edit').css('display', 'none');
            $('#div-edit').addClass('hide');
        }

    })

});
```

For completion, here is the .html and .css files:

**notes.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h3>
        Add Notes
    </h3>
    <div id="div-add">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="content">Content</label>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" id="content"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add</button>
            <p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="div-list">
        <h3>View/Edit</h3>
        <ul id="list">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="div-edit" class="hide">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit-name"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="content">Content</label>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control" id="edit-content"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button id="save" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save</button>
            <button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Remove</button>
            <button id="cancel" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**styles.css:**

```
body {
    padding: 20px;
}
#list {
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
#list li {
    padding: 20px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-width: 1px;
}
#list li.selected{
    background-color: #B8D0E6;
}
#list li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.div-name {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 260px;
}
.div-date{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
}
.edit-content {
    width: 500px;
}
#div-list {
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#div-add {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 500px;
}
#div-edit {
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#div-edit.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: "more" object oriented? How is this object oriented?

Comment: Have you made an attempt to implement "object-oriented"  type of behavior that you can share?  This is leaning more towards a "tell me how to do it" type of question as opposed to a "this is my attempt at doing it, please give me feedback" type of question.  There are any number of resources on the internet about how to implem ent object-oriented behaviors in javascript. I don't see where this has been attempted here, so not sure how valuable you will find a code review at this stage.

Answer (score 5):

To start with, I do not know JavaScript.  I do know HTML and CSS, though.

Your CSS file has no problems at all according to the W3C validator (http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).  However, I do not think you need this line:

```
background-color: #fff;
```

This is just setting your `background-color` property to white.

Your HTML has three problems, according to the W3C validator (http://validator.w3.org/check).

1. You don't have a `<title>Title</title>` tag in the `<head>`
2. You close both your `<input ...>` tags like this: `</input>`, and the validator wants you to just close them like this: `<input ... />`

Your JavaScript text looks like it has an error here (according to this validator: http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php):

```
console.log("name: ", name)
```

I think that should be:

```
console.log("name: ", name);
```

As for object orientation, I cannot help there as I do not know JS.  It appears to work very well as it is without needing to be more object orientated, though.

This is a JSFiddle of your code with my changes that you can work with: http://jsfiddle.net/g66q0hto/

Comment: Objection! I know this is old, however, `input`, `meta` and similar tags actually _don't need to be closed_ at all. `<input ...>` is just fine.